# How do I pass the app service name from my terraform deployment to an app service deployment in devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, cicd

I have a release pipeline in Azure Devops with two stages:

1. Create Infrastructure - Creates resources in azure (resource group, app service plan, etc..)
2. Deploy Artifact - deploys a .NET build artifact to an Azure app service that is created in Stage 1

In stage 2, I am running the task "Deploy Azure App Service", which asks for a couple parameters {Azure subscription & App Service Name}. Each parameter provides a drop-down list of options to choose from. This is problematic because the the app service doesn't exist yet, so there is no way to reference it, and the dropdown list is blank.

Is there a way to use the output variables in stage 1 and feed those to the parameters of stage 2?

Answer (score -1):

I think this could be achievable using a null resource to write out some data to a file first:

```
resource "null_resource" "create_app_service_data" {
  count = var.deploy ? 1: 0
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "chmod +x ${path.module}/scripts/write_json.sh; ${path.module}/scripts/write_json.sh"
    environment = {
      APP_SERV_NAME = split(output.app_serv_id, "/")[8]
      APP_SERV_SUB_ID = split(output.app_serv_id, "/")[2]
      APP_SERV_RG_NAME = split(output.app_serv_id, "/")[4]
    }
  }
}
```

After this step in your Terraform you would have a file in the same working directory as your TF code so you would need to do some work to get it to the directory that you want it to be in for usage, here's some example bash to run to get it there:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
APP_SERV_NAME = "${APP_SERV_NAME}"
APP_SERV_SUB_ID = "${APP_SERV_SUB_ID}"
APP_SERV_RG_NAME = "${APP_SERV_RG_NAME}"

JSON_STRING=$( jq -n \
                  --arg app_serv_name "refs/heads/$FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME" \
                  --arg sub_id "refs/heads/$FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME" \
                  --arg rg_name "refs/heads/$FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME" \
                  '{"app_serv_name": $app_serv_name, "sub_id": $sub_id, "rg_name": $rg_name}')

echo "$JSON_STRING" > app_service_data.json
```

Following that you would need to set some output variables to be used in follow on tasks/jobs/stages like so:

```yaml
- bash: |
    APP_SERV_NAME=$(cat app_service_data.json | jq '.app_serv_name')
    SUB_ID=$(cat app_service_data.json | jq '.sub_id')
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appServiceName;isoutput=true]$APP_SERV_NAME"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=subscriptionId;isoutput=true]$SUB_ID"
  displayName: Set Outputs For Deployment
  name: setVariablesForDeployment
```

From there I imagine you could expand the variables inside of your task like so:

```yaml
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: $(setVariablesForDeployment.subscriptionId)
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: $(setVariablesForDeployment.appServiceName)
```

See more documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) on output variables for Azure DevOps. I realize there are a lot of connected steps here but I'm not acutely aware of how to grab values of Terraform outputs and get them into the pipeline otherwise.